# Android ePos caller ID app help!

Tags: applications, caller-id

Hi basically I have a new ePos system at my shop, they have a feature where it automatically inputs the callers number into the system to bring up their ‘profile’ from previous orders they’ve made.

However their caller ID app runs from Android phones and obviously we use landline phones.

I just wondered if anyone knows a way to have the android app triggered by a landline phone without having to do call forwarding? The invoxia VoiceBridge would have been perfect but of course they have discontinued it.

I just want a cell phone to receive a call alongside the landline phone.

Thanks!

Comment: In a lot of countries landline phones are are more and more converted into (DSL) internet connections with VoIP phones. If your landline connection is already using those techniques you could install a VoIP app on your phone and connect it via Wifi to the internet connection. Then you just have to enter the VoIP credentials of your telephone number from the landline into the VoIP client. Or use a router that handles the VoIP connection but let local analog/DECT and Smartphones connect and use the VoIP feature.

Comment: So I’d get a VoIP line and phone in then install the VoIP app on my smartphone or the landline phone?

Comment: Typically the router is the VoIP end point and the old phone is connected to the router + the VoIP client on the smartphone, too.